# Why Edge browser does not process Javascript setTimer() like other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I have noticed a problem with the Edge browser and I couldn't figure out what the problem really is:

I wrote a simple webpage with javascript to run some code, which makes use of the `setTimer()` function. It works well in Opera browser. On Edge browser, this code is not running, but other similar code I found online works well.

I simplified the code to the following.

```html
<HTML>

<BODY>
<p>Test body</p>
<button id="BtnStartCalculation">Start Calculation</button>

<script>
//Test script
BtnStartCalculation= document.getElementById("BtnStartCalculation")
BtnStartCalculation.addEventListener('click',BtnStartCalculationClick,false);

var niter=0;

function BtnStartCalculationClick(event){
    //Start the calculation by running iterations
    document.write("<p>Start program</p>");
    CalculationCycle();
}

function CalculationCycle(){
    niter+=1;
    document.write("<br>Status   niter= "+ niter.toString());
 setTimeout(CalculationCycle,200); //Give some time to redraw
}

</script>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

After clicking the button, the code should continuously print status, as it continuously calls `CalculationCycle()` via a `setTimer()` function. Edge browser seems to ignore it, for some reason.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the `setInterval()` function is more adapted to your case instead of recursion (function calling itself), isn't it ?

Comment: Did you mean `setTimeout` instead of `setTimer` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> document.write("Start program");
>
> document.write("Status niter= "+ niter.toString());    setTimeout(CalculationCycle,200); //Give some time to redraw

I think the issue is related to the document write method (above code), after using this method to display the running status, it will clear the page original information, such as the button and the JavaScript script.

As a solution, you could add a container to display the output, such as a div.

Code as below:

```
<button id="BtnStartCalculation">Start Calculation</button>

<div id="output">

</div>
<script>
    //Test script
    BtnStartCalculation = document.getElementById("BtnStartCalculation")
    BtnStartCalculation.addEventListener('click', BtnStartCalculationClick, false);

    var niter = 0;
    function BtnStartCalculationClick(event) {
        //Start the calculation by running iterations
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<p>Start program</p>";
        CalculationCycle();
    }

    function CalculationCycle() {
        niter += 1;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<br>Status   niter= " + niter.toString();
        setTimeout(CalculationCycle, 200); //Give some time to redraw
    }
</script>
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]

Comment: This worked well, thanks. Still weird, though that browsers react differently.

Answer (score 0):

by using inspect element , i find out that your  are been overwrite by your document.write() which make your script only run once

```
    function CalculationCycle(){
    niter+=1;
    document.write("<br>Status   niter= "+ niter.toString());
    setTimeout(CalculationCycle(),200); //Give some time to redraw
 }
```

Your CalculationCycle put the () after it should be working

Comment: Hi, thanks. The double bracket 'kind of' worked. The iteration information appears but in a few seconds it 11,000 lines appear. This kind of suggests that the function or timeout is being called too often, or maybe the timeout value is ignored. Putting larger values for the timeout didn't help.